# Xcode indicate potenial leak of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

First of all i am a n00b. After long time of trying and research i decided to get some external help.
My Project:
i made a book for children. Now i am analyzing my code and try to get rid of some leaks (level 1 + 2 Crash after a while).
Here is my Code

```
- (void)loadView {

    _oben = YES;
    _unten = NO;

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]; 

    UIImage *cover = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Umschlag.png"]; //Here it says "Potential leak..
    //..allocated on line 141 (thats at self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cover];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    [self.view addSubview:image];
    [image release];

    UITextView *text1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(184, 700, 400, 100)];
    text1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    text1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    text1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CoverTextKey1", nil);
    [self.view addSubview:text1];
    [text1 release];

    [self addButtonNext];
    [self addSwipeDown];
    [self addSwipeUp];
}
```

Any ideas?
It would be really cool if anyone could help me! 
Thanks in advance Planky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Potential leak allocated on line 141:
>
> self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

That line is **over-retaining** the object because `alloc-init` returns a retained object (+1) and the property setter also retains the object (+2).

You can use a temporary variable...

```
UIView *temp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view = temp;
[temp release];
```

...or autorelease to fix this:

```
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
```

Comment: thanks, now i putted in all the missing releases and did the autorelease and all the potential leaks are gone. sadly still crashes but thats another topic. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: Another alternative is to assign to the instance variable rather than the property.  Of course, in that case you must be sure that the property does not currently contain a non-nil pointer.  (If unsure, assign nil to the property first.)

Answer (score -1):

Use `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` or `- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` instead. They don't cache the image, `imageNamed:` does.

Comment: What's wrong with caching the image. If you use the same image in more than one place it only uses the memory for one. Your method will mean that the image takes up memory wherever it is used.

Comment: The problem is that the system internally never release that cache, even though your UIImage object is released and dealloc-ed. So avoid using `imageNamed:` if you have many images, unless you need to reuse the images very frequently. http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Comment: Yeah - I'm going to take the word of a blog post from 2009 about an issue with iOS2.x that was fixed in 3.x while I'm looking at writing for iOS5. Sure, don't put large images in the cache (as the docs say), but if you maintain references to objects in the cache - it won't get cleared, so if you release your references in didReceiveMemoryWarning properly you give the cache a chance to clear itself. There are cases where you don't want caching, but to say **never** use `imageNamed:` is just wrong.

Comment: I did not say never use `imageNamed:`. Although the bug was fixed in 3.x, its default caching behavior is not friendly to large images. Better memory usage can be achieved if you handle the cache by customized mechanism for images in big size.